# "unknown command" shown when creating a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The following script produces an error:

```
CREATE TABLE BOTTLE
(
    Bottle_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    BottleSize NUMBER(10,0) ,
    Shape VARCHAR(30) ,
    GlassColor VARCHAR(30) ,
    BottleInventory NUMBER(10,0) ,
    CostPerBottle NUMBER(5,2) ,

    constraint BOTTLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (Bottle_ID)
);

create table BOTTLE_VENDOR
(
    Vendor_ID VARCHAR(30) not null,
    VendorName VARCHAR(20),
    Vendor_Straddr1 VARCHAR(100),
    Vendor_Straddr2 VARCHAR(100),
    Vendor_City VARCHAR(20),
    Vendor_State VARCHAR(20),
    Vendor_Zip CHAR(5),
    Vendor_Phone VARCHAR(20),
    PrincipalContact VARCHAR(30),       

    constraint pk_BOTTLE_VENDOR primary key (Vendor_ID)
);

create table BOTTLE_ORDER
(
    Bottle_Order_ID VARCHAR(30) not null,
    BottleOrderDate DATE,
    Vendor_ID VARCHAR(30),

    constraint pk_BOTTLE_ORDER primary key (Bottle_Order_ID),
    constraint fk_BOTTLE_ORDER foreign key (Vendor_ID) references BOTTLE_VENDOR(Vendor_ID)
);

create table SHIPMENT
(
    Shipment_ID VARCHAR(30) not null,
    ShipmentDate DATE,
    ReceivedQuantity INTEGER,
    ReceivedDate DATE,
    Bottle_Order_ID VARCHAR(30),

    constraint pk_SHIPMENT primary key (Shipment_ID),
    constraint fk_SHIPMENT foreign key (Bottle_Order_ID) references BOTTLE_ORDER(Bottle_Order_ID)
);

create table BOTTLE_ORDER_LINE
(
    Bottle_Order_ID VARCHAR(30) not null,
    Bottle_ID VARCHAR(30) not null,
    BottleOrderQuantity INTEGER,
    ActualPricePerBottle NUMBER(5,2),

    constraint pk_BOTTLE_ORDER_LINE primary key (Bottle_Order_ID,Bottle_ID),
    constraint fk_BOTTLE_ORDER_LINE foreign key (Bottle_Order_ID) references BOTTLE_ORDER(Bottle_Order_ID),
    constraint fk_BOTTLE_ORDER_LINE2 foreign key (Bottle_Order_ID) references BOTTLE(Bottle_ID)
);
```

Here is what exactly shown:

> Error starting at line : 37 in command -  constraint fk_SHIPMENT foreign key (Bottle_Order_ID) references BOTTLE_ORDER(Bottle_Order_ID)
>   Error report -
>   Unknown Command

The error drives me crazy and don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: show the complete script please

Comment: have you tried running again this script?I assumed, you have highlighted line 37 only before pressing F5.Its a common error when highlighting a portion of the script then running the script or pressing F5 or equivalent key in your developer.

Answer (score 0):

The following line (the last line you've posted) does not match your table definitions:

```
constraint fk_BOTTLE_ORDER_LINE2 foreign key (Bottle_Order_ID) references BOTTLE(Bottle_ID)
```

it should read:

```
constraint fk_BOTTLE_ORDER_LINE2 foreign key (Bottle_ID) references BOTTLE(Bottle_ID)
```